# Load different files from let

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there a way to load different files passed as arguments in Ruby let definition? This is the code that I sue to load file in rspec:

```
let(:xml_file) { File.read(File.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'xml', 'example1.xml')) }
```

I need something like this:

```
let(:xml_file) { File.read(File.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'xml', #{file})) }
```

Can you propose some solution?

Comment: Why not just write `file` instead of `#{file}`?

Comment: Please tag also with [tag:rspec]? `let` does not exist in general Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Just make file name a variable and define it per describe/context

```
let(:xml_file) { File.read(File.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'xml', file_name)) }

context '1' do
  let(:file_name) { 'foobar_1.xml' }

  it 'test sth' do
    xml_file # should be spec/fixtures/xml/foobar_1.xml
  end
end

context '2' do
  let(:file_name) { 'foobar_2.xml' }

  it 'test sth' do
    xml_file # should be spec/fixtures/xml/foobar_2.xml
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use an specific file on each test, you can define another `let` on each context or describe section:

```
let(:xml_file) { File.read(File.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'xml', file))}

describe "first set of tests" do
  let(:file) { "file_1.txt" }

end

describe "second set of tests" do
  let(:file) { "file_2.txt" }

end
```